# How to resolve type with parameter and use this parameter when resolving in child dependencies

Tags: dependency-injection, unity-container

In Unity, is it possible to resolve a type with a parameter then furthermore inject this specific parameter in child dependencies?

E.g
Parent has constructor with parameter Dummy.
Parent resolves several other types which also has a Dummy parameter in their constructors - in which I want the specific parameter injected.

Possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you provide the parameter at resolve-time, this is the default behaviour.

In this example, `"dummyValue"` is injected into both constructors (`MyImplementation` and `MySomething`):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main( string[] args )
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();
        container.RegisterType<IInterface, MyImplementation>();
        container.RegisterType<ISomething, MySomething>();
        var instance = container.Resolve<MyImplementation>( new ParameterOverride( "dummy", "dummyValue" ) );
    }
}

internal class MyImplementation : IInterface
{
    public MyImplementation( ISomething dep, string dummy )
    {
    }
}

internal class MySomething : ISomething
{
    public MySomething( string dummy )
    {
    }
}

internal interface IInterface
{
}

internal interface ISomething
{
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Looking at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660920(v=pandp.20).aspx, is DependencyOverride a better alternative?

Comment: "better" in which regard?

Comment: In that it overrides all of the specified type and not those matching the name? Also, it seems it can override dependencies marked with the dependency attribute. I'm aware I explicitly stated parameters in the constructur, but it looks like the DependencyOverride handles more scenarios (unless I have multiple instances of the same type of course). Do you agree?

Comment: I think it depends on what you're trying to achieve. Personally, I don't like these overrides and prefer handmade factories, because they (to me) tend to be clearer and less fragile